# How can I deduce the distance formula from a point to a straight line?

Tags: geometry

Consider:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
reg = ImplicitRegion[a x + b y + c == 0, {x, y}]
pt = {x0, y0}
RegionDistance[reg, pt]
```

The distance formula from a point to a straight line cannot be derived using the above code.

Without knowing how to solve it, I attempted to replace it with the following code through other means:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
line=a x+b y+c==0
pt={x0,y0}
pol=Apply[Subtract,line];
Flatten@CoefficientList[pol,{x,y}];
A1=Coefficient[pol,x];
B1=Coefficient[pol,y];
C1=Select[pol,FreeQ[x|y]];
distance=Abs[A1 pt[[1]]+B1 pt[[2]]+C1]/Sqrt[A1^2+B1^2]
```

How can I change the first code to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we check the examples in document of `RegionDistance`, we'll see most of the examples are about specific graphic primitives (`Line`, `Disk`, etc.). This isn't too surprising, because functions like `ImplicitRegion` are so general, and general problems are always hard to handle. This inspires us to try replacing the `ImplicitRegion` with an `InfiniteLine` as a workaround:

```
ptfunc[y_] = {x /. Solve[a x + b y + c == 0, {x}][[1]], y}
(* {(-c - b y)/a, y} *)

reg = InfiniteLine[ptfunc /@ {0, 1}]
(* InfiniteLine[{{-(c/a), 0}, {(-b - c)/a, 1}}] *)

pt = {x0, y0};
dis = RegionDistance[reg, pt]
(* Sqrt[(c + a x0 + b y0)^2/(a^2 + b^2)] *)

dis // FullSimplify[#, {a, b, c, x0, y0} ∈ Reals] &
(* Abs[c + a x0 + b y0]/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] *)
```

---

### Update

As pointed out by user64494 in comment below, I've implicitly assumed `a!=0` in the solution above, so let me add a rigorous and simpler solution making use of **2nd syntax of** `Hyperplane`:

```
reg = Hyperplane[{a, b}, -c];

pt = {x0, y0};
dis = RegionDistance[reg, pt]
(* Abs[(c + a x0 + b y0)/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]] *)

dis // Simplify[#, {a, b} ∈ Reals] &
(* Abs[c + a x0 + b y0]/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] *)
```

Comment: In  the first line of your code `a != 0` is implicitly assumed. You'll see the difference, making use of `Reduce` instead of `Solve`.

Comment: @user64494 OK, I've added a rigorous solution, see my update.

Comment: I think the formula `Abs[(c + a x0 + b y0)/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]]` is simply implemented in `RegionDistance`, not derived there. The above is not any "a rigorous and simpler solution". Compare with my answer.

Comment: @user64494 That depends on how we define "deduce"/"derive". Since OP has used `RegionDistance` in his first trial, I think using `RegionDistance` fits OP's requirement.

Comment: `Hyperplane`, up to [its documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hyperplane.html?q=Hyperplane), allows `a==0&&b==0` (see "Hyperplane represents the set ...  "  and the next line in  Details). Also `reg=Hyperplane[{0, 0}, -c]` results in `Hyperplane[{0, 0}, -c]`.

Comment: @user64494 I think this isn't a problem, because the question already states `a x + b y + c == 0` is a "straight line", then `a`, `b`, `c` should be a set of parameters that defines a valid straight line. (You may argue that `Hyperplane[{0,0}, ...]` should trigger a warning, though. But it's worth pointing out `Hyperplane[{0, 0}, -c] // Graphics` results in warnings. )

Comment: Let us look in that documentation again: "`Hyperplane[a, p]`
represents the hyperplane with normal `n` passing through the point `p`." Each point of the plane has two coordinates, but you write down only `c` in `reg = Hyperplane[{a, b}, -c];`.

Comment: @user64494 I'm using 2nd syntax of `Hyperplane`: "`Hyperplane[n,c]` represents the hyperplane with normal `n` given by the points `x` that satisfy `n.x==c`. "

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround:

First a visualization of a selected instance:

[image]

Derivation:

```
pt = {x0, y0};
line = a x + b y + c == 0;
tri = Triangle[{pt
   , {0, y} /. First@Solve[line, y] /. {x -> 0}
   , {x, 0} /. First@Solve[line, x] /. {y -> 0}
   }]
```

> Triangle[{{x0, y0}, {0, -(c/b)}, {-(c/a), 0}}]

```
ans = (TriangleMeasurement[tri, {"Height", pt}]) // 
  FullSimplify[#, {a, b, c, x0, y0} ∈ Reals] & (* `FullSimplify` step copied from xzczd's answer*)
```

> Abs[c + a x0 + b y0]/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]

which after (unnecessary) formatting becomes:

```
ans /. {x0 -> Subscript[x, 0], y0 -> Subscript[y, 0]} // 
 Map@TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: `Solve` produces only a generic solution, not taking into consideration all possibilities of parameter values. Compare with my answer.

Comment: In particular, you don't consider the cases when `line` is parallel to x-axis or y-axis.

Answer (score 3):

Given a point and a line:

```
pt={x0,y0}
line= a x+b y+c==0;
```

If we project the point: pt={x,y} perpendicularly onto the line we have the point: pp on the line closest to pt, giving the distance of the point from the line. Therefore, we have 2 equations one that pp={xp,yp} is on the line. The second comes from: pt-p0 is perpendicular to the direction of the line. Therefor, the scalar product from a vector in direction of the line and (pt-pp) must be zero

```
pt={x,y};
pp= {xp,yp};
```

The direction of the line: A vector perpendicular to the line is: {a,b}. Therefore, the direction is: {-b,a} (check: take the scalar product {a,b}.{-b,a})

```
dir= {-b,a}
```

Therefore we have 2 equations to determine pp:

eq = {{a, b} . pp + c == 0, dir. (pp - pt) == 0 }

And we get pp by:

```
ppsol= pp /. Solve[eq, {xp, yp}];
```

With this we get the distance:

```
Norm[pt -ppsol]
```

We can put all together in a distance function:

```
dist[pt_, {a_, b_, c_}] := 
 Module[{pp = {xp, yp}, dir = {-b, a}, eq, ppsol}, 
  eq = {{a, b} . pp + c == 0, dir . (pt - pp) == 0};
  ppsol = pp /. Solve[eq, pp][[1]]; 
  Norm[pt - ppsol]
  ]
```

Now, let us try if this works. A line from {0,1} to {1,0} has {a,b,c}=={1,1,-2} and a point {1,1} has a distance of 2/Sqrt[2] from this line:

```
dist[{2, 2}, {1, 1, -2}]

1/Sqrt[2]
```

Comment: -1. The result of `ppsol` is `{(1/(2 (a^2 + b^2)))(-2 a c - a b p0 + b^2 p0 + b^2 x - 
   a b y + \[Sqrt]((2 a c + a b p0 - b^2 p0 - b^2 x + a b y)^2 - 
      4 (a^2 + b^2) (c^2 + b c p0 + b^2 p0 x + b c y + 
         b^2 p0 y))), (1/b)(-c + (a^2 c)/(a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 b p0)/(
   2 (a^2 + b^2)) - (a b^2 p0)/(2 (a^2 + b^2)) - (a b^2 x)/(
   2 (a^2 + b^2)) + (a^2 b y)/(2 (a^2 + b^2)) - (1/(2 (a^2 + b^2)))
   a \[Sqrt]((2 a c + a b p0 - b^2 p0 - b^2 x + a b y)^2 - 
       4 (a^2 + b^2) (c^2 + b c p0 + b^2 p0 x + b c y + b^2 p0 y)))}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct approach which demonstrates the difficulties caused by 5 parameters $a,b,c,x0,y0$.

```
Minimize[{Sqrt[({x, y} - {x0, y0}) . ({x, y} - {x0, y0})], 
a*x + b*y + c == 0 && a^2 + b^2 > 0}, {x, y}] // First
```

> `Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x0^2], (x0 == 0 && c == 0 && a > 0 && b == 0) ||  (x0 == 0 && c == 0 && a < 0 && b == 0)}, {Sqrt[(c + a*x0)^2/a^2],  (x0 > 0 && a > 0 && b == 0) || (x0 > 0 && a < 0 && b == 0) ||  (x0 < 0 && a > 0 && b == 0) || (x0 < 0 && a < 0 && b == 0)},  {Sqrt[(c^2 + a^2*x0^2)/a^2], (x0 == 0 && c > 0 && a > 0 && b == 0) ||  (x0 == 0 && c > 0 && a < 0 && b == 0) || (x0 == 0 && c < 0 &&  a > 0 && b == 0) || (x0 == 0 && c < 0 && a < 0 && b == 0)},  {Sqrt[(c + b*y0)^2/b^2], (x0 > 0 && a == 0 && b > 0) ||  (x0 > 0 && a == 0 && b < 0) || (x0 < 0 && a == 0 && b > 0) ||  (x0 < 0 && a == 0 && b < 0)}, {Sqrt[(c + a*x0 + b*y0)^2/(a^2 + b^2)],  (x0 < 0 && a < 0 && b > 0) || (x0 > 0 && a > 0 && b > 0) ||  (x0 > 0 && a > 0 && b < 0) || (x0 > 0 && a < 0 && b > 0) ||  (x0 > 0 && a < 0 && b < 0) || (x0 < 0 && a > 0 && b > 0) ||  (x0 < 0 && a > 0 && b < 0) || (x0 < 0 && a < 0 && b < 0)},  {Sqrt[x0^2 + y0^2], (x0 == 0 && c == 0 && a == 0 && b > 0) ||  (x0 == 0 && c == 0 && a == 0 && b < 0)},  {Sqrt[(c^2 + a^2*x0^2 + b^2*x0^2 + 2*b*c*y0 + b^2*y0^2)/(a^2 + b^2)],  (x0 == 0 && c > 0 && a > 0 && b > 0) || (x0 == 0 && c > 0 && a > 0 &&  b < 0) || (x0 == 0 && c > 0 && a < 0 && b > 0) ||  (x0 == 0 && c > 0 && a < 0 && b < 0) || (x0 == 0 && c < 0 && a > 0 &&  b > 0) || (x0 == 0 && c < 0 && a > 0 && b < 0) ||  (x0 == 0 && c < 0 && a < 0 && b > 0) || (x0 == 0 && c < 0 && a < 0 &&  b < 0)}, {Sqrt[x0^2 + (b^2*y0^2)/(a^2 + b^2)],  (x0 == 0 && c == 0 && a > 0 && b > 0) || (x0 == 0 && c == 0 &&  a > 0 && b < 0) || (x0 == 0 && c == 0 && a < 0 && b > 0) ||  (x0 == 0 && c == 0 && a < 0 && b < 0)},  {Sqrt[x0^2 + y0^2 + (c*(c + 2*b*y0))/b^2],  (x0 == 0 && c > 0 && a == 0 && b > 0) || (x0 == 0 && c > 0 &&  a == 0 && b < 0) || (x0 == 0 && c < 0 && a == 0 && b > 0) ||  (x0 == 0 && c < 0 && a == 0 && b < 0)}}, Infinity]`

Its execution takes more than dozen minutes.

```
FullSimplify[%, Assumptions -> a^2 + b^2 > 0 && {a, b, x0, y0} ∈ Reals]
```

> `Piecewise[{{0, b == 0 && c == 0 && x0 == 0}, {Sqrt[(c + a*x0)^2/a^2],  b == 0 && x0 != 0}, {Sqrt[c^2/a^2], b == 0 && x0 == 0 && c != 0},  {Sqrt[(c + b*y0)^2/b^2], a == 0 && (c != 0 || x0 != 0)},  {Sqrt[(c + a*x0 + b*y0)^2/(a^2 + b^2)], a != 0 && b != 0 && x0 != 0},  {Abs[y0], a == 0 && c == 0 && x0 == 0},  {Sqrt[(c + b*y0)^2/(a^2 + b^2)], x0 == 0 && a != 0 && b != 0 &&  c != 0}}, (Abs[b]*Abs[y0])/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]]`

At last,

```
FullSimplify[Piecewise[{{0, b == 0 && c == 0 && x0 == 0}, {Sqrt[(c + a*x0)^2/a^2], 
    b == 0 && x0 != 0}, {Sqrt[c^2/a^2], 
 b == 0 && x0 == 0 && c != 0}, 
  {Sqrt[(c + b*y0)^2/b^2], a == 0 && (c != 0 || x0 != 0)}, 
  {Sqrt[(c + a*x0 + b*y0)^2/(a^2 + b^2)], 
 a != 0 && b != 0 && x0 != 0}, 
  {Abs[y0], a == 0 && c == 0 && x0 == 0}, 
  {Sqrt[(c + b*y0)^2/(a^2 + b^2)], 
 x0 == 0 && a != 0 && b != 0 && 
      c != 0}}, (Abs[b]*Abs[y0])/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]] - 
  Sqrt[(c + a*x0 + b*y0)^2/(a^2 + b^2)], 
 Assumptions -> a^2 + b^2 > 0 && {a, b, x0, y0} ∈ Reals]
```

> `0`

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[(c + a*x0 + b*y0)^2/(a^2 + b^2)] - 
RealAbs[(c + a*x0 + b*y0)]/Sqrt[(a^2 + b^2)], 
 Assumptions -> a^2 + b^2 > 0 && {a, b, x0, y0} ∈ Reals]
```

> `0`

Comment: Please notice that, if the goal of the question is "obtaining the same output as the second sample", your answer doesn't meet the requirement.

Comment: @xzczd: Why do you think so? My answer is `RealAbs[(c + a*x0 + b*y0)]/Sqrt[(a^2 + b^2)]`.

Comment: But the `RealAbs[(c + a*x0 + b*y0)]/Sqrt[(a^2 + b^2)]` is obtained by manual analysis, right? With `FullSimplify`, we only obtain a lengthy `Piecewise[…]`.

Comment: @xzczd:  You are right.